# Can Drupal be used to send an email if an existing contact's name is changed

Tags: civicrm-entity, drupal-rules

I'm wondering if it is possible to use the Drupal Rules module with CiviCRM Entity to send me an email when, for example, someone has taken an action (like made a donation) that updated the contact record and (for example) changed their first name. I can see a trigger "Before updating a civicrm contact" that then offer "Changed" and "Unchanged" values which could be compared (Condition: data comparison) but, that trigger does not seem to work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The extension CiviRules is maybe an option. You can find it in the extension directory https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules and the latest documentation is at https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/ .

Comment: This may be the best option in this particular case, because CiviCRM Entity has its Rules event triggered in hook_civicrm_post(), in which case the original entity has already been altered in the db, and there's really no way to look back.